# What type of convex constraint is defined by SQRT?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix and $\forall k, x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
 The distance with respect to this matrix is defined as

$ \|x_i -x_j\|_A :=  \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^TA(x_i-x_j)} $.

Now, suppose we have the constraint $$\sum_{(x_i,x_j) \in D} \|x_i -x_j\|_A = \sum_{(x_i,x_j) \in D}  \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^TA(x_i-x_j)} \ge 1$$
I know (by reading  in a paper), that this is a $\textbf{convex constraint in } \mathbf{A}$, but cannot verify that (because of the sqrt).

Can anyone help me please or give a hint? Why is it convex in $A$? Is it?
More importantly, what type of convex constraint  is that (linear, quadratic, SOC, SDP?)

Comment: Any thoughts can be helpful.

Comment: How is $D$ defined?

Comment: $D$ is just a set of pairs. Some domain.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking if $\|x\|_A$ is a concave function of $A$.

Comment: Maybe should compute the Hessian and prove it is negative semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer and it is just my thoughts on it. May be you can convert it into a set of equivalent constraints.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j}t_{ij}&\geq 1 \\\
t_{ij} &\geq 0 \\\
\|x_i -x_j\|_A &\geq t_{ij}
\end{align}
You can square both sides of the third inequality.